# Extracting Days and Timings from a String in Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery to extract a User's Schedule data from a String.

The strings look like this:

```
{"0,1,2,3,4,5,6":[["11:00","21:30"]]}
```

-> This means that the User is scheduled to for 7 days a week from 11:00 am till 9:30 pm

```
{"0,1,2,3,6":[["11:00","21:30"]],"4,5":[["11:00","22:30"]]}
```

-> This means User will be online from 11:00 am till 9:30 pm on Sat-Wed and  11:00 am till 10:30 pm on Fridays

I want to split this into three columns, Days and Start/End time. So far I have been able to get the desired data for the first example using REGEXP_Extract Function.

| Days | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 | 11:00 | 21:30 |

Not sure how to go about doing it for the second example.

Here is the query I have used.

```sql
select 
name,
periods, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, "{\"(.*)\":.*") as Days,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, "\\[\\[\"(.*)\",") as Start_time,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, ",\"(.*)\"\\]\\]") as  end_time,

from `projectid.dataset.table` where is_active_cache=1 limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '{"0,1,2,3,4,5,6":[["11:00","21:30"]]}' schedule UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"0,1,2,3,6":[["11:00","21:30"]],"4,5":[["11:00","22:30"]]}'
)
SELECT days, start_time, end_time
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST (REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(schedule, r'"([0-9,]*)":')) days WITH offset
  JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(schedule, r'\[\["(\d{2}:\d{2})"')) start_time WITH offset USING (offset)
  JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(schedule, r'"(\d{2}:\d{2})"]]')) end_time WITH offset USING (offset);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: I recommend this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query:

```
select
  name,
  periods,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, "{\"([^\"]*)\":.*") as Days,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, "\\[\\[\"(.*)\",") as Start_time,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(periods, ",\"(.*)\"\\]\\]") as End_time,
from `projectid.dataset.table`
where is_active_cache = 1
  and REGEXP_CONTAINS(periods, "{\"[^\"]*\":[\\[\\[\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\"\\]\\]]}")
limit 100
```

where `"{\"([^\"]*)\":.*"` matches the string that starts with `{"`, followed by a group of characters that does not contain `"`, followed by `":`, and then any number of characters until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with less cluttered code

```
select null as days, null as start_time, null as end_time from unnest([1]) where false 
union all
select * except(schedule, pos) from (
  select schedule, part, div(offset, 3) pos, mod(offset, 3) as col
  from your_table, unnest(regexp_extract_all(schedule, r'"([^"]*?)"')) part with offset
)
pivot (any_value(part) for col in (0,1,2))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]